# How to interpretate shapvalue of a single observation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, shap

I trained an XGBoost model to predict excavation damages. There are 123 features and the target classes are 1 (damage) or 0 (no damage). Now for each prediction, I am required to give a list of most important features for this certain instance. So I tried Shap to get shapevalues for a single observatrion by `explainer = shap.Explainer(model, input_array) shap_values = explainer(input_array)` But I have two questions about interpretating the result:

1. I think the shap value should be a list of values, in which positive value means the contribution to positive result and negative value means the contribution to negative result. But after I tried about 5 instances, I found **only positive values**. Below is an example of the shape values for an instance. Most of the features have the shap value of 0, which means that these features are usefless for this prediction I think. But I don't understand why there is no negative value.

```
array([[0.00000000e+00, 9.92100000e+01, 1.00000000e+00, 4.00000000e+00,
        2.50000000e+01, 4.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+01, 6.00000000e+00,
        1.13380000e+02, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00,
        1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00,
        1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.63470000e+04, 2.42600000e+03, 6.90000000e+01, 2.98800000e+03,
        4.22000000e+03, 2.30000000e+01, 4.60759023e+02, 1.09184603e-01,
        3.67600000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 5.77357590e+01,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 4.16226424e+03, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

2. I found from somewhere that, the predicted probability = the aggregation of shap values + expected value. But when I tried to aggregate shap values of instance A and instance B. Instance A has the predicted probability of 0.38, and the aggregated shap value of 111147.29. Instance B has the predicted probability of 0.74, and the aggregated values value of 31077.21. Why A has a higher aggregated shap value than B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding your first question (only positive values):**

You're correct that SHAP values represent a contribution to the prediction. To elaborate: they contribute to a base value, calculated as `Base value + contrib. 1 + contrib. 2 + ... = Final value`. If your base value is low, you might mostly see positive SHAP values. Another possibility is that your model is biased, which could also result in mainly positive values.

**Regarding your second question (relationship between SHAP values and predicted probabilities):**

You've understood the relationship between SHAP values and predicted probabilities correctly: the predicted output is the sum of the SHAP values and the expected value (the average prediction across the training dataset). However:

- You should aggregate the SHAP values per feature, not across all features.
- Be cautious when comparing aggregated SHAP values between different instances like A and B. These explanations are instance-specific, and varying numbers of features may contribute to the predictions for different instances.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Regarding question 1, I got from the shap values that `.base_values = array([1.04877459])`. I am not sure if this base value is low or high, but it seems like the reason can be the biased model. I will try to change the parameter of my model and see how it looks like.

Comment: @JiarongLi You're welcome. A base value of 1.05 is actually quite significant. In the context of a binary classification problem, this suggests that the model is biased towards predicting "damage" even before considering the features.

Comment: I think maybe that is because I set the scale-pos-weight to 38 (count of negative cases/count of positive cases, as suggested by the XGBoost document). Could you please elaborate 'a base value of 1.05 is quite significant'?

Comment: I set the scale-pos-weight to 1, and use the new model to calculate shap values. But still there are all positive values. And the base value becomes -2.53.

Comment: Regarding the base value, I just noticed that a base value of 1.05 is notably higher than the midpoint of 0.5 on this scale. This means that your model already leans toward predicting "damage" even before incorporating the impact of any features. But this is suitable, it is possible that the model tends to one class, but feature interactions add up to the other class.

Comment: In your case of imbalanced data, your initial approach of scaling up the minority class was correct. If my answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1133249) :)